# NodeJS behind McAfee Web Gateway in direct proxy mode (not transparent)

Tags: node.js, proxy

I have a node application sitting behind a corporate proxy -- McAfee Web Gateway in direct proxy mode (not transparent).  I have access to a username/password and domain for authentication but not sure how to use them for this.

For other proxies that use NTLM, I can generally use cntlm and it works well but does not work well in this case.  I am also successful when behind an http proxy that just uses "basic" authentication.  However, I have never run into this kind of beast before and was wondering where to start.

Thanks!

Comment: I'm having the same issue here - did you have any luck fixing it?

Comment: Unfortunately, no.  We switched it over to run inside of the NodeWebKit which has the ability to detect the Windows proxy settings and use those automatically.